# Reason why applications aren't stored in the Home-Folder?

Tags: macos, unix

**I wonder why Apple don't put all applications in an applications folder inside the Home-Folder.** So they could offer a hole new mac for each user.

Every file is user specific, except for the applications. Is there a reason for this? Or just "too complicated" because every user want to have access to Safari and Third-Party Apps?

> Is it just Apple or is it a UNIX design decision?

Is there an explanation/documentation/ operation system design?

Comment: If you just install all applications in a folder called Applications for each user - they can have their own copy of each and every third party application. I assume you are asking why Apple put Safari and other system apps that are delivered with OS X in /Applications rather than hiding it and hard linking each app to the home folder of each new user when you make them an account? (i.e. - what problem are you trying to solve here other than researching why a decision was made?)

Comment: Actually no problems... i just wonder why. There is this great opportunity to separate each user and then they creat a "public" applications folder

Comment: Join us in [chat] for any general discussions as well as questions that basically ask "why" - we close them as off topic on the main site since they end up not being useful when viewed in the definition of what we want Stack Exchange / Ask Different to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's design is not at all a traditional or typical UNIX layout for user files, user preferences or application files and preferences so I would say this is just Apple.

They do document exactly how developers are supposed to design OS X apps to take advantage of the "canonical" locations where files and preferences should be stored so that each user can decide to install any application in one or several locations.

- /Applications
- /Another volume/Aplications
- ~/Applications
- or anywhere else on the drive since on OS X - you don't need to place an application anywhere as long as the user can read from the folder - an app should run and store things in the proper pace (which is NOT in the application folder itself).

Here are three articles I would start with to learn more:

- [OS X File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [OS X File System Details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemDetails/FileSystemDetails.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH8-SW1)
- [Apple OS File System Overview (iOS and OS X combined)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) ***Start Here*** and *skip past the iOS part* and go directly to Table 1-2 for OS X summary of important folders.

Answer (score 0):

Not that long ago, the system came set up with an Applications folder in the Home Directory. I continue to keep one and recommend the practice for decluttering the main Applications folder of smaller and seldom-used apps.

Comment: With a setup like that, how do you solve the problem of several users wanting to use the same apps?

Comment: Users have access to /Applications. They can also have aliases galore in ~/Applications. But all Apple apps do want to live in /Applications, that's where updaters will look.